# How to install SQL Server 2008 R2 in Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: sql, windows-7, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to install SQL Server 2008 R2, but I get error in the setup.

Tell me that I need to install a .Net Framework 3.5, but is already installed!

What am I missing?

Which one is the correct installer.

[image: sql setup message and .net]

Answer (score 0):

got to the below link, Download and install .Net framework 3.5 and then try

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=21

Comment: Tells me that I need to go to Control Panel->Programs->Set on or Set Off Windows Features. I'm downloading full .net 3.5 package ..

Comment: No you dont just download and install it